# What the version mean in the abstract class SQLiteOpenHelper of Android

Tags: android, sqliteopenhelper

There is a parameter in the constructor of the virtual class SQLiteOpenHelper called version(like below shows)

```
public SQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        this(context, name, factory, version, null);
    }
```

What i want to know is what's the meaning of the version?Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the Database version you ship with the Application. So in the future if you want to add a table or delete a column or anything which differs from the previous Database version. This version Number will come handy.

This is an example of how I manuplated DB on upgrades of my application: 
The method is defined by the framework, onUpgrade()

Class Level Variable:

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;
```

Check against the current version:

```
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            if (oldVersion < 2) {
                db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATEX);
            }
            if (oldVersion < 3) {
                db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATEC);
            }
            if (oldVersion < 4) {
                final String ALTER_TBL = "ALTER TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE1
                        + " ADD COLUMN Vcost text;";
                final String ALTER_TBL1 = "ALTER TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE1
                        + " ADD COLUMN Vmedicine text;";
                db.execSQL(ALTER_TBL);
                db.execSQL(ALTER_TBL1);

                final String ALTER_TBL2 = "ALTER TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE2
                        + " ADD COLUMN Dcost text;";
                final String ALTER_TBL3 = "ALTER TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE2
                        + " ADD COLUMN Dmedicine text;";
                db.execSQL(ALTER_TBL2);
                db.execSQL(ALTER_TBL3);

            }

        }
```

So it checks based on all versions of the DB and it acts according to the current version which is present on the device.

Answer (score 0):

Its a way for you to version your database, which is why you're also required to override the onUpgrade method to handle database upgrades. So say you launch your app with a SQLite database and then later on you change your tables. You would then increment the database version, and when the app updates the onUpgrade method would be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Version :

number of the database (starting at 1); if the database is older, onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase, int, int) will be used to upgrade the database; if the database is newer, onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase, int, int) will be used to downgrade the database

for more detail visit [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#SQLiteOpenHelper%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int%29)